# Composite of Homeomorphisms is Homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In this ProofWiki article, [Composite of Homeomorphisms is Homeomorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Composite_of_Homeomorphisms_is_Homeomorphism)

> By definition of homeomorphism, $f$ and $g$ are both bijections.
>
> From Composite of Bijections is Bijection it follows that $g∘f$ is also
> a bijection.
>
> Similarly, also by definition of homeomorphism, $f$ and $g$ are both
> continuous mappings.
>
> From Composite of Continuous Mappings is Continuous it follows that
> $g∘f$ is also a continuous mapping.
>
> Hence the result, from definition of homeomorphism.

I feel like the proof is not complete, as by the definition on ProofWiki of a [Homeomorphism](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Homeomorphism/Topological_Spaces)

> **Definition 1**
> $f$ is a homeomorphism if and only if both $f$ and $f^{−1}$ are
> continuous.

I think the proof should also mention that $(g \circ f)^{-1}$ is also continuous as $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ and each $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ are continuous by the definition of homeomorphism. And still, composite of continuous mapping is continuous.

Hence, $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ is continuous.

Is my extra step needed in the proof? Or it is implied somehow in the proof itself?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: There is no real need for a separate proof of this whole fact, as in any category, also Top, the composition of isomorphisms  is an isomorphism. Once you do it for categories, we know it for Set (isomorphism = bijection), Top (isomorphism = homeomorphism), Gr (isomorphism = group isomorphism) , Ring, etc.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand why my mathematics teachers promised me that I'd never be any good at anything. Thank you for pointing out another horribly stupid blunder in the ever more unreliable and worthless ProofWiki. I have fixed this appalling omission and now maybe there's one page which maybe isn't quite as egregious as it used to be. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct to say that specifying continuity of the inverse is necessary. It is not implied by the given proof. For instance, we can find two continuous bijections that are not homeomorphism, and such that their composition isn't a homeomorphism either. Hence, continuity of the inverse cannot be assumed from the given proof.

Let $\mathbb R_0$ be $\mathbb R$ as a set with the discrete topology, let $\mathbb R_1$ be $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric topology, and let $\mathbb R_2$ be $\mathbb R$ with the indiscrete topology, i.e. the only open sets are the empty set and the whole space. Then the identity maps $\mathbb R_0 \longrightarrow \mathbb R_1 \longrightarrow \mathbb R_2$ are continuous bijections which are not homeomorphisms, as is their composition.